# Should I use MaxiVista or Air Display for a Windows 7 monitor extender?

Tags: ipad, windows

I'm about to go on a trip and I'm wondering if anyone has tried both MaxiVista and Air Display as monitor extenders for Win7. MaxiVista was first on a PC and Air Display is still in beta for PC.

Comment: Note that Air Display is no longer in beta for PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both.

Air Display is better at updating the iPad display quickly and smoothly.  Air Display also has some additional features, like being able to use the touchscreen as a mouse, and it can be used with both Windows and Mac, so I'd say it is a better deal.

Maxivista is a little easier to get set up on Windows.  It just worked.  I had to futz around a bit to get Air Display to work, but it wasn't too hard (just have to remember to Run as Administrator).

For more details on what I found when I compared them, see [my blog](http://undefinedvalue.com/2011/01/28/air-display-vs-maxivista).

Answer (score 1):

I use Maxivista and have no problems. I use it on my Windows boxes for a very long time and it just works as promised.

Answer (score 1):

Balexandre: The Maxivista App does not cost $40, it cost $9.99.

MaxiVista is awesome. I never thought that a monitor can be that fast over W-LAN.

Comment: try see the price here: http://www.maxivista.com/docs4/09/shop.php to compare with AirDisplay, you need to include desktop mirroring!

Comment: balexandre, you are looking at the price for the full Windows version of Maxivista, not the iPad version, which is currently $9.99 in the App Store.

Answer (score -1):

if you only use windows, then you **should go buying** [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/docs4/09/shop.php) as it's stable and works great.

Air Display was firstly for iPad as a extra monitor, and they are now doing the Windows part witch can take time.

**But there again**... the [Air Display beta](http://avatron.com/spt/download/) **is free** while MaxiVista **costs 40 bucks** (or $100 is you want mirroring and high res)

:o)

*my recommendation*: try Air Display for free :)

Comment: Air Display beta is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks for the info, though $9.99 (http://itunes.apple.com/app/air-display/id368158927?mt=8) beats 40 :) and its stable and works fantastic on Windows as well on the Mac!

Comment: Please stop saying that MaxiVista costs $40.  MaxiVista for iPad is $9.99, same as Air Display.  (The $40 and $100 prices are for versions of MaxiVista that run on other Windows machines, not on iPads.)

Comment: http://www.maxivista.com/docs4/09/shop.php remember that you need to include Mirroring if you are comparing the same features with Air Display! When I go to MaxiVista website, and products, that's what I find: http://www.maxivista.com/multi_monitor.htm - What am  doing wrong here, please correct me... I'm lost!

Comment: MaxiVista sells a version of their product that lets you use another *Windows* machine as a secondary display for a Windows machine. *That* is the thing that costs 40 bucks, but that is not what we are talking about--we are talking about using an *iPad* as a secondary display. The MaxiVista product that lets you use an iPad as a secondary display costs $9.99.